# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when inserting integer values into hash table

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't know where is the error (Insert into table). It's fragment of my code (inserting into open addressing hash table). Linear and double addressing are good, but with this (quadratic function addressing) its something wrong

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -848
    at openaddresshash.OpenAddressHash.insertKwadratowe(OpenAddressHash.java:101)
    at openaddresshash.OpenAddressHash.main(OpenAddressHash.java:261)
Java Result: 1
```

I know that is something wrong with this line:

```
int index = ((start + (c1 * i) + (c2 * i * i))) % size;
```

But in my opinion its everything good becouse my function (index) should be looks like:

```
h(k,i) = (h'(k) + c1*i + c2*i^2) mod m
where h'(k) = k mod m
```

My code:

```
for( int d = 25; d<=2500; d+=25)
{
    int liczba=4*d;
    OpenAddressHash hstb = new OpenAddressHash(liczba);
    int jj=2*d;
    hstb.AdresowanieKwadratoweDane(1, jj);

    Losowania los = new Losowania(); // random values
    los.Losowe(liczba); 

    for(int yy=0; yy<liczba; yy++)
    {
        hstb.insertKwadratowe(los.trzy[yy]);//trzy is a table with random values 
        if((yy%(Math.ceil(liczba/50)))==0)
        {
            AdresowanieKwadratowe.println( liczba+" "+yy+" "+hstb.s );
        } 
        hstb.s=0;
    }

}

static public class SLOT
{
    public int key;
    public STATUS stat;

    public SLOT()
    {
        stat = STATUS.INVALID;
    }
}

public void AdresowanieKwadratoweDane(int c1, int c2)
{
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.c2 = c2;
}

public OpenAddressHash(int n)
{
    table = new SLOT[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    {
        table[i] = new SLOT();
    }
}

public int insertKwadratowe(int key)
{
    int size = table.length;
    int start = key%size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        s++;
        int index = ((start + (c1 * i) + (c2 * i * i))) % size;
        if (table[index].stat == STATUS.INVALID ||
                table[index].stat == STATUS.DELETED)
        {
            table[index] = new SLOT();
            table[index].key = key;
            table[index].stat = STATUS.OCCUPIED;

            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public void AdresowanieKwadratoweDane(int c1, int c2)
{
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.c2 = c2;
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I know where the error is: it's at line 101 of OpenAddressHash.java. You probably have a negative integer somewhere, or an integer overflow. Use your debugger.

Comment: Something's probably wrong with the formula to calculate `index`. Hard to figure out, not knowing what's really going on in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what happens in insert when we have an `OpenAddressHash` with size 2000, and set the c2 variable to 1000 (as you do in your outer loop when d=500).

Then `i` can go up to 1999, in which case you compute:

```
int index = ((start + (c1 * i) + (c2 * i * i))) % size;
```

The subexpression

```
 c2   * i    * i
 1000 * 1999 * 1999
```

gives -298966296, and so chances are that you get a negative index, unless `start + (c1 *i)` will make it good. But there is no indication it would do that, as `c1` is always 1 as far as I can see, and `start` is something smaller than `size`.

Apart from that, you get also negative index when your key to insert is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I might be incorrect, but from looking at the way you calculate the index:

```
int index = ((start + (c1 * i) + (c2 * i * i))) % size;
```

If the value of start is 0, then the index will be equal to size.  Although, size represents the quantity.  So, unless you reduce it by 1, you could end up with the exception you are seeing.  For the first iteration, anyways.

Comment: "If the value of start is 0, then the index will be equal to size" - how do you figure? I don't see how any number modulo size could be equal to size.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the exception occurs in the `insertKwadratowe` method, and there's only one array access in that method, the problem must lie in calculating the index, i.e. this line:

```
int index = ((start + (c1 * i) + (c2 * i * i))) % size;
```

Perhaps start, or c1 or c2 are negative, or perhaps you are getting an integer overflow with your multiplication resulting in a negative number.

Comment: start can easily go negative, for example when the argument `key` is negative. Also, assuming c2=5000, i must be *less than*  655 to avoid overflow.